# ListView is not getting updated while typing in TextField in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listener

Populating data in ListView while typing in TextField but Data is being populated on Done button of keyboard. The Data is coming from Google Autocomplete Api.

I tried to update list while typing but nothing working.

> TextField Code

```
TextField(
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          controller: searchAddressController,
                          focusNode: searchFocus,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                Icons.search_rounded,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: MyColors.locationfieldback,
                              hintText: "Add Location",
                              focusedBorder: border,
                              disabledBorder: border,
                              enabledBorder: border,
                              border: border,
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'regular',
                                  color: Colors.grey[500],
                                  letterSpacing: 1.5),
                              errorBorder: border,
                              focusedErrorBorder: border,
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'regular',
                                  color: Colors.grey[500],
                                  letterSpacing: 1.5),
                              contentPadding:
                                  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 12, 20, 12))),
```

> ListView Code

```
ListView.builder(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemCount: _placeList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      onLoading(context);
                                      getLatLong(
                                          _placeList[index].placeId, index);
                                    },
                                    title: Text(
                                      '${_placeList[index].description}',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                      maxLines: 3,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'semibold'),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                })
```

Search method and Listener

```
searchAddressController.addListener(() {
      _onChanged();
    });

_onChanged() {
    if (_sessionToken == null) {
      setState(() {
        _sessionToken = uuid.v4();
      });
    }
    searchLocation(searchAddressController.text);
  }

  Future<GooglePlaceAutocompleteResponse> searchLocation(String input) async {
    String baseURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json';
    String request = '$baseURL?input=$input&key=$kPLACES_API_KEY&sessiontoken=$_sessionToken';
     Dio dio = Dio();
    var response = await dio.get(request);
    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Log.e("ADDRESS RESPONSE", response.data);
        var responseObj = GooglePlaceAutocompleteResponse.fromJson(response.data);
        setState(() {
          _placeList = responseObj.predictions;
        });
        return responseObj;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load predictions');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Log.e("EXCEPTION AUTOCOMPLETE", e);
    }
  }
```

[image]

Getting response while typing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`searchLocation(searchAddressController.text);` place this under setState. As well as, you can use `async` and `await`.

```
_onChanged() {
    if (_sessionToken == null) {
      setState(() {
        _sessionToken = uuid.v4();

      searchLocation(searchAddressController.text);
      });
    }
  }
```

**Edited**

If you use `bottomSheet`, please use `stateBuilder` with `StateSetter`

Comment: Tried but not working

Comment: you can call `searchLocation ` from your textfield when your value changed  `onChanged: (text) => searchLocation(text),`

Comment: i have attached listner to my textfield and while typing i'm getting response from server but list not getting updated

Comment: Instead call `searchLocation()` in the `onChanged` property of the text field like JahidulIslam has suggested.

Comment: i was getting response while typing but not getting updated , and i called `searchLocation` directly in textfield in `onChanged' method nothing is working

Comment: I think your list is not updated, can you share the `placeList` code

Comment: I have added my list code and also update last image

Comment: i think your list not updated you can try with key `key: Key(placeList.length.toString()),` in listview.builder,  if placeList update then key value will be changed

Comment: still not working,  any idea

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Actually i had my list inside bottomSheet that why it was not getting updated, Now it is working by adding own `StateBuilder'.

Comment: yap, for my previous comment I just told you that your list was updated or not? and glad to see your enthusiasm.

Comment: please have a look, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling `setState` on `_onChanged()` when you call the function. Do this,

```
_onChanged() async{
  if (_sessionToken == null) {
    setState(() {
      _sessionToken = uuid.v4();
    });
  }
    await searchLocation(searchAddressController.text);
    setState((){});
  }
```